# Popup com uma lupa

Tags: jquery, popover

Eu tenho uma página com um combo que permite múltiplas seleções de seus itens.

Se o usuário selecionar apenas um item, ao fechar o combo é exibido um texto sobre o item selecionado. caso, porém, o usuário selecionar múltiplos itens, ao fechar o combo o texto exibido é "X escolhidos", sendo X a quantidade de itens selecionados.

Sei que se o usuário abrir novamente o combo ele poderá ver os itens selecionados mas desejo criar um botão, com uma lupa, para ser colocado ao lado desse combo o qual, ao ser clicado, exiba um popup com a lista dos itens selecionados no combo.

[image: combo para a seleção]

[image: combo selecionado um elemento]

[image: combo selecionado 3 elementos]

Segue abaixo o código gerador do combo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /*PRODUTOS*/
        $('#produto').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: false,
            nonSelectedText: '[Selecione uma opção]'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @jp_almeida Faltou você incluir uma informação importante: está usando o plugin **multiSelect**. Eu não conhecia o plugin e ao procurar pela documentação dele (para responder sua pergunta) vi que o próprio já faz esse trabalho de inserir os itens selecionados em uma outra lista (que você pode manter visível pro usuário). Então qual é a sua dúvida? Como inserir os itens na outra lista? Ou, como deixar a outra lista sempre visível?

Comment: Eu quero que ao usuário clicar na lupa ao lado do combo de produtos aparecer tipo uma tela com os produtos selecionados. Tipo um balão.

Comment: renan, você tem alguma ideia de como faz isso? Eu achei somente com ancora e não imagem como eu quero.

Comment: @jp_almeida Tem como postar aqui nos comentários a solução que encontrou? Nunca vi esse plugin mas posso ver se consigo algo :)

Comment: renan eu achei isso:  <script>  
    $(function() {
        $("#mypopover").popover({
            trigger:'click', 
            html:true, 
            content:function(){return $("#popover-content").html();}}
        ).on('click',function () {
            $('.multiselect').multiselect();
        });  
    }); 
</script>

Comment: No caso ele colocou o select em um botão, eu tentei fazer isso mas não ficou legal.

Comment: <button id="mypopover" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content='
        <div class="btn-group">
            <select class="form-control multiselect" multiple="multiple">
                <option>Choice 1</option>
                <option>Choice 2</option>
                <option>Choice 3</option>
            </select>